# How to show number of indents with little arrows in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I remember that I saw some code from the web that has little arrows in front of each line to identify its number of indents, which turned out to be very helpful when the code is long. But I can't find that web page anymore so I wonder if anyone knows how to add that kind of indicator in Jupyter Notebook? Thanks!